# libpqxx prepared statements nonnull checks for pointer types

Tags: libpqxx

I'm a newbie to SQL overall and libpqxx as well.I'm trying to build a basic application where I just need to use prepared statements to execute very simple jobs.
I have started with libpxx 4.0 version and I implemented codes like this:

```
pqxx::work txn( *conn );
auto result = txn.prepared( "my_insert" )( x->getId( ), x->isIdSet( ) )( x->getUser( ), x->isUserSet( ) )(x->getCreatedAt( ), x->isCreatedAtSet( ) ).exec( );
txn.commit();
```

Now I had to change to version 6.4 and realized the prepared function is deprecated and I should use the exec_prepared function. Okay. BUT I'm really missing the "nonnull" condition. For certain reasons I'm working with a lot of pointers and I need a convenient way to pass on these values to the database API. I could write something like:

```
auto result = txn.exec_prepared( "my_insert", (x->isIdSet() ? std::to_string(x-getId()) : "null"), ....);
```

This could work in some cases but when I try to insert "null" as string into a smallint field I get an sql error (what is reasonable though).
As types differ I can't use the ?: operator to return string/int/etc... on true branch and nullptr on false branch.

I couldn't find a proper documentation about the library. They have a doc [here](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/a01480.html) but if you want to find out more about a certain function there's literally nothing there.

Honestly even the deprecated `.prepared(...)` function doesn't work properly with 6.4 for me. I tried `txn.prepared("whatever")(y->z->getA(), y->z != nullptr).exec()` form and I got segmentation fault when y was a valid non-null pointer type and z was null-pointer. I expected the function wouldn't touch the value before checking on the condition but apparently it's not the case.

I have a prepared statement with 8 parameters 6 of them being a pointer type (shared_ptr) and it would be extremely messy if I have to come up with a ridiculous solution to check all the parameters one-by-one and having to write 200 lines just to be able to call this function properly.

Anyone out there having a proper solution? As I mentioned I'm a newbie so I might miss an important part there. Help me out please ^^

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old. But here's what you do:

```
const auto& id{ x->isIdSet()
    ? std::optional<std::string>{x-getId()} : std::nullopt };
auto result{ txn.exec_prepared("my_insert", id, ....) };
```